# Proving that if $a+b = c+d$ and $a!b! = c!d!$ then either $a = c$ and $b = d$ or $a = d$ and $b = c$

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

I recently have been thinking about how many ways it is possible to get from one square to another on a square grid using the fewest possible number of orthogonal steps. (i.e., using the fewest number of the xiangqi general's move, how many paths are there?) For example, to do an up-right diagonal, you can go up then right or right then up, so for this path, the answer is 2. For a knight's move, there are 3 ways: UUR, URU, and RUU. We can obviously consider paths rotated multiples of 45 degrees, so I will assume the path goes up and right, and it goes more up than right.

I was thinking that for each move a certain number of steps away from the starting point, each point might have a different number of ways of getting there. For a point (a,b) each path can be described by a permutation of the multiset that contains a U steps and b R steps. Therefore, the number of paths of (a, b) is the multinomial coefficient:
$${a+b \choose a, b} = \frac {(a + b)!} {a!b!}$$
If (a, b) and (c, d) are the same number of steps away from the starting point, then $a+b = c+d$. So, if we are saying that (a, b) and (c,d) have the same number of paths to them, then the above is also equal to:
$${c+d \choose c, d} = \frac {(c + d)!} {c!d!} = \frac {(a + b)!} {c!d!}$$
So, we are only a little algebra away from:
$$a!b! = c!d!$$
The whole aim was to show that the number of paths is unique for this distance away from the origin. So I want to prove (or disprove) that (a,b) must be the same point as (c, d) ignoring rotations, which amounts to the question I asked. It seems pretty intuitive that it could be true, but I'm not sure what direction to go to prove it and can't find anything online.

Comment: I guess this type of path I am describing is called a 'North-East lattice path' according to Wikipedia, except that I disregard those that end below the diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the thing:

If $j < k; m \ge 0$ then $\frac {(j+m)!}{j!} < \frac {(k + m)!}{k!}$ and if $m < \min (j,k)$ then $\frac {j!}{(j-m)!} < \frac {k!}{(k-m)!}$.

This is clear as $\frac {(j+m)!}{j!}=\prod_{i=1}^m (j+i)< \prod_{i=1}^m (k + i) = \frac {(k + m)!}{k!}$ and $\frac {j!}{(j-m)!}=\prod_{i=1}^m (j-m+i)! < \prod_{i-1}^m (k-m+i)! = \frac {k!}{(k-m)!}$.

So  $\frac {(j+m)!}{j!} = \frac {(k + m)!}{k!}$ or $\frac {j!}{(j-m)!}= \frac {k!}{(k-m)!}$ $\implies j = k$.

Which means $(j\pm m)!k! = j!(k\pm m)!\implies k = j$ (assuming, of course, that $m \ne 0$.

.....

Now if $a + b = c + d$ and if we let $m= c-a = b-d$ then we have:

$a!b! = c!d! \implies a!(d+m)! = (a+m)!d!\implies (c-m)!b! = c!(d-m)!$.

If $m \ne 0$ then $a=d$ and $b = c$.

If $m = 0$ then $a = c$ and $b=d$.

Comment: I don't get why you needed to show that it was $\pm m$. Isn't it true that if the lower m is positive we can use $a!(d+m)! = (a+m)!d!$ and otherwise use $(c-m)!b! = c!(d-m)!$ ?

Comment: I was trying to avoid cases.  I didn't want to say if $m > 0$ then $a= d$ and from there we conclude $b=c$ and if $m < 0$ then $b=c$ and from there we conclude $a=d$.  It seemed to me say $a!(d_m)!=(a+m)!=(c-m)!b = c!(d-m)!$ simultaneously shows $a=d$ and $b=c$ whether or not $m$ is positive or negative (so long as $m\ne 0$).  Likewise I didn't have to show *both* results for $\frac {(j+m)!}{j}$ and $\frac {j!}{(j-m)!}$.  But I really want to to avoid cases and wologs....

Comment: One can argue an easier to read proof would be Case 1: a> c; let m = a-c; so d=b+m and (c+m)!b! = c!(b+m)! so $c=b$ and as $a+b=c+d$ then $a=d$ Case 2: a=c; then b=d; Case 3: a< c; let m=c-a so b=d+m and a!(d+m)!=(a+m)!d! so a = d and therefore b=c.... But that... galls me... as the cases don't really matter and aren't that difference and m being positive or negative isn't relevant.

Comment: Perhaps a more compact proof would be if for pos integers if $j-k = l-m> 0$ then $\frac {j!}{k!} < \frac {l!}{m!} \iff j<l$ so if $j-k = l-m\ne 0$ then $m!j! =k!l!$ implies $j=l; m=k$.  So $a+b=c+d\implies a-c=d-b$ so $a!b!=c!d!$ implies $a=d;b=c$ if $a\ne c$ and implies $b = d$ if $a =c$.  But that's... kind of hard to read and inelegant.

Answer (score 5):

Without loss of generality, $a\le b$ and $c\le d$. Write $n=a+b=c+d$ so you want

$$ \binom{n}{a}=\binom{n}{c} \implies a=c. $$

Writing $n=2k$ or $n=2k+1$ now, we can go a step further and try showing

$$ \binom{n}{0},\binom{n}{1},\binom{n}{2},\cdots,\binom{n}{k} $$

is a strictly increasing sequence (note $0\le a,c\le k$). For this, suppose $\ell<k$ and write

$$ \binom{n}{\ell}<\binom{n}{\ell+1}.$$

Use the formula for binomial coefficients to rearrange this into an equivalent form. Note there should be cancellation, and also that $\ell<k \implies 2\ell+1<n$.

Comment: Ah, of course, then we have $\binom{n}{\ell}<\binom{n}{\ell+1}\iff \frac {n!}{\ell!(n - \ell)!}<\frac {n!}{(\ell+1)!(n - \ell - 1)!}\iff \frac {1}{n - \ell}<\frac {1}{\ell+1} \iff 2\ell+1<n$ which is true. Thank you.